# Ошибка: Could not enable linger: No such process

Tags: linux, systemd

Хочу запустить lingering на Ubuntu Server 18.04, но он что-то не запускается:

```
# loginctl enable-linger andreymal
Could not enable linger: No such process
```

На десктопной Ubuntu и в Arch при этом всё работает.

Пытался читать `journalctl -f`, но ни единой строчки по этому поводу там нет.

Каких-то встроенных дебагов не нашёл, читать strace не умею (но если кому-то интересно, то вот: https://pastebin.com/YVHdrC0K)

Как понять, чего ему не хватает и что надо починить?

Comment: [это](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/462845/110559) не про то?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin про то, но там в ответе enable-linger просто работает и всё, а у меня почему-то не работает. Я даже `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` проверил — присутствует, пользовательский `systemd --user` успешно запускается при логине и работает (могу делать start/stop/enable/disable/status с опцией `--user` без рута), но вот enable-linger всё равно не работает

Comment: я вообще-то не в курсе, что это такое и для чего нужно, но элементарная логика подсказывает, что сделать чего-то «enable» надо всё-таки от имени root-а, т.е. что-нибудь вроде `$ sudo ... enable...`, а если для самой процедуры требуется переменнай окружения (`xdg_чего-то-там`), то её надо явно передать «в обход» sudo. что-то вроде `$ sudo xdg_чего-то-там=значение команда`. примерно: `$ sudo XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR loginctl enable-linger пользователь`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin декорационная решёточка, которую я поставил перед командой в тексте вопроса, намекает, что я и так запускаю от рута. Общепринятое обозначение же) Впрочем, хоть с рутом, хоть без рута — всё равно не работает. Вообще, по идее эта команда должна всего лишь создавать пустой файл `/var/lib/systemd/linger/andreymal`, но что-то ей мешает

Comment: так создайте сами: https://serverfault.com/a/849280/292034

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так костыль же, у меня в системе что-то сломано, надо как-то выяснить что)

Comment: ха! «сломано»! у вас в системе стоит systemd (и присные его)? ну, вот, этого вполне достаточно, чтобы считать систему «сломанной». а если что-то где-то как-то умудряется работать, то это не благодаря, а вопреки (это всё, конечно, шуточки, но в каждой шуточке…). и, кстати,, про «костыль». уж какой systemd — «костыль», так «всем костылям костыль»!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub><sup>*В Ubuntu 20.04 снова всё сломалось, по этому поводу обновил ответ*</sup></sub>

Оказалось, дело в том, что в целях безопасности я скрыл список процессов в `/proc` с помощью опции монтирования `hidepid=2,gid=999` (читатель может наблюдать такую опцию действующей на каждом втором shared-хостинге, например).

Хотя systemd-logind работает от рута, для него сбрасываются capabilities, из-за чего он тоже теряет доступ к `/proc` и пишет `No such process` (доступ можно вернуть подключением CAP_SYS_PTRACE, но это небезопасно).

Баг ли это или фича, и зачем вообще systemd'у лезть в `/proc` ради банального touch, и какому конкретно процессу это надо, непонятно, но сейчас отключение `hidepid`

```
sudo mount -o remount,hidepid=0 /proc
```

решило проблему.

Без выключения `hidepid=2` обнаружился вариант дописать дополнительную группу в drop-in файл для `systemd-logind` ([патч из PLD Linux](https://github.com/pld-linux/systemd/commit/5ad7745fe63cadf3940ba00da430c326191947f9#diff-c1a02fde99e3c1468306aa01fe779b7e), [патч патча](https://github.com/pld-linux/systemd/commit/452e45bc153cd7e562e82f2374dfb31705c32e49)):

```
# /etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service.d/procadmin.conf
[Service]
SupplementaryGroups=999
```

где `999` — gid из опции монтирования `/proc` (просто название группы тоже подходит). Потом перезапускаемся/перезагружаемся и всё работает.

(Просто `Group=999` прописать нельзя, так как изменение основной группы процесса влияет на права создаваемых системных каталогов, из-за чего systemd-logind вопит о проблемах с доступом и отказывается нормально работать.)

---

Леннарт, чини давай!

[image]